# Better looking PDF bookmarks

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

Does anybody know if I can improve the visual appearance of bookmarks in a PDF.  My marketing dept wants me to make them look more "webby" - by which they mean they want them to look more "designed" rather than plain text links.

Cheers, Stan

Comment: Not that it matters, but I hate "webby" links in pdfs. I always get the feeling they will send me out to the browser.

Comment: Marketing departments are so annoying.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make them look more "webby". You can change the bookmark text so that it is bold, italic or bold and italic, and you can change the color of the text, but that's it.

The reason for this is that the style of the bookmarks (with the exception of the stuff I mentioned above) is entirely dependent on the PDF reader that you're using. The makers of Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader, etc, have the final say on how their bookmarks will look.